# Qiskit throws error when changing basis gate for transpilation

Tags: qiskit, transpile

I want to transpile a circuit composed of CNOT and 1Q gates into Rzz, CNOT and 1Q gates such that the total number of 2Q gates is minimized. In the example below, I would like the three gates to be replaced with a single Rzz gate.
However, just changing the basis gates in the transpiler pass throws an error (shown below). Any suggestions?

```
import qiskit as qs
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.cx(1, 0)
qc.rz(1.2,0)
qc.cx(1,0)

qc_3 = qs.transpile(qc, basis_gates=['rzz','x', 'sx', 'rz'], optimization_level=3)
```

Error:

```
TranspilerError: "Unable to map source basis {('rz', 1), ('cx', 2)} to target basis {'sx', 'rzz', 'rz', 'x', 'reset', 'barrier', 'snapshot', 'delay', 'measure'} over library <qiskit.circuit.equivalence.EquivalenceLibrary object at 0x7faa11f85be0>."
```

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.20.1', 'qiskit-aer': '0.9.1', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.6.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.18.1', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.5', 'qiskit': '0.32.1', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

[EDIT]
Upgrading the Qiskit package stops the error but is still unable to transpile the input circuit into a single Rzz.

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.22.3', 'qiskit-aer': '0.11.2', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.6.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.19.2', 'qiskit': '0.39.4', 'qiskit-nature': '0.2.2', 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

Comment: I am not experiencing this error running that code in JupyterLab (presuming `import qiskit as qs` is also run), but it's still not transpiling into one RZZ at any optimization level. What environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Running the same code as yours gives me the following circuit for `qc_3`, with no errors:

[image]

My guess is that there is a version difference between my machine to yours. I use `{'qiskit-terra': '0.22.3', 'qiskit': '0.39.4'}`. Can you please check yours? (`qiskit.__qiskit_version__`).

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading the qiskit package stops throwing the error. However the transpiler is still not able to replace the initial circuit with a single Rzz gate. Any idea how to achieve that? Right now it is only decomposing each CX gate into Rzz gate individually